# Ajax call in MobX: MobX observer: Store is not available! Make sure it is provided by some Provider

Tags: ajax, reactjs, axios, mobx

I'm migrating from a traditional React application with the tree-structure to a state management structure with MobX.

Currently, my individual components propagate down data from an Ajax call made by the parent/grandparent, which works fine.

Now I wish to change this so that I don't work in the tree structure anymore due to the change of complexity and dependency of parallel grandchildren/children.

Say I do an `axios.get` in `componentDidMount` of a `<Parent1/>` React class. How do I then access the data using `MobX`?

What I've tried so far:

Creating a `store.jsx` that looks as such:

```
import { observable } from 'mobx';
const axios = require('axios');

class Store {
    @observable parentdata;
    loadParent = () => {
        let that = this;
        axios.get("/api/parent").then(function(response){
            that.parentdata = response.parentdata;
        }).catch(function(error){
         // Error handling
        })
    };
}

export default Store;
```

My `ReactDOM` is rendered in `container.jsx` which contains all parents, meaning also `<Parent1/>`. In `container.jsx` we do the following:

```
import { Provider } from 'mobx-react';

import Store from './store/store.jsx';
let store = new Store();
```

and

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Main />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

.. in the end.

In the render method of `container.jsx` I don't do anything with `<Parent1/>` - it simply renders the component as normal(that's the idea here, right?)

In `parent1.jsx`, I remove the previous `axios.get` and add these:

```
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';


@inject('store') @observer
export default class Parent1 extends React.Component {
// ..... 

 componentDidMount () {
        this.props.store.loadParent();
```

After that, the error is provided: `MobX observer: Store 'parentdata' is not available! Make sure it is provided by some Provider`

Where did I go wrong in binding the data here?

Edit: Removing `@inject` and only having `@observer` results in: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadParent' of undefined`

Comment: This line:  that.parentdata = response.parentdata is suspicious. Does response.parentData exist? Axios response data is in res.data as far as I know.

Comment: Nothing in the code you have provided is wrong. The error message you've shown will only occur if you try and use `@inject('parentdata')` somewhere and `parentdata` hasn't been provided by a `Provider`. Have you either changed some code for the purposes of this example, or have you got some other code that's trying to inject `parentdata` ?

Comment: @cbll i would go back and change all refs to your store to match capital casing. sounds to me like your store is declared with an uppercase letter and injected with lowercase letter. can you verify?

Answer (score 0):

Few things to address:

Assuming you named your `parentData` store `'store'` and not `'Store'` like the classname, the Provider looks like it's configured correctly

Here's how I'd change the store itself:

```js
import { observable } from 'mobx';
const axios = require('axios');

class Store {
    @observable parentdata;
    loadParent = () => {
        // There's no need to clone this if you're using arrow functions
        axios.get("/api/parent").then((response) => {
            this.parentdata = response.parentdata;
        }).catch(function(error){
         // Error handling
        })
    };
}

export default Store;
```

In the component, I might do this:

```js
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';


@inject('store') @observer
export default class Parent1 extends React.Component {
  // ... //
  componentDidMount () {
      this.props.store.loadParent();
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.props.store.parentData) { return (<div>Loading...</div>) }

    const { parentData } = this.props.store
    return (<pre>{JSON.stringify(parentData, null, 4)}</pre>)

  }

}
```

My suspicion is that your store is case sensitive and mistakenly named.

A nifty tricks to debugging could be to `console.log` important variables or  attach them to a window object to test.

eg:

```js
class Parent1 {

  componentDidMount() {
    window.Parent1 = this
    window.Parent1Props = this.props
    window.Store = this.props.store // or `this.props.Store` check case sensitivity!
  }


  // Open browser console and try to access your now global variables
```